# Is the intersection of two star-shaped sets star-shaped?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the intersection of two [star-shaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-shaped) sets star-shaped?

I don't think so but can't think of an example.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it can be.

No, it does not have to be.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

HINT: A star-shaped set is connected. A $+$ sign is star-shaped. Find a way to position two of them so that the intersection is a two-point set.

Answer (score 4):

Intersection of two star shaped domain is again a star shaped domain provided previous two domains are star shaped with respect to same point. Otherwise the result is not true in general.See the counterexample given by Scott.